# How can I pause a code that is running in Sublime?

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, pause

I am running a python script in sublime text 3 on a laptop. The process takes a very long time to complete. I need to go from the place I am working to home. So I want to pause the process and put the laptop in sleep mode and later when I reach home, I will resume the process again from it was paused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "stop" and "resume" long time running Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299349/how-to-stop-and-resume-long-time-running-python-script)

Comment: Sublime doesn't have any explicit support for that; it just runs the program you tell it to run. So your program would need to pause and resume itself. Note that the solution in the duplicate above won't directly work because you can't run interactive programs in Sublime without a third party package, but the same concept applies.